# (SVD) why does the first right singular vector minimise the sum of squared distances to a projection?

Tags: svd, singular-values

for days now i've been searching the whole internet to find an answer on this question but I didn't find anything.
Can anyone please help me on that or give me a hint?

I need to prove that the first right singular vector minimises the sum of squared distances to a projection

Thanks.

Comment: What projection?  The distance between what?  Can you add some more context?

Comment: I suspect the result you're trying to go for is that the "best" rank 1 approximation to a matrix $A$ is given by $u_1 \sigma_1 v_1^T$. But this does not hold in any nicer form.